# How can I reverse sub-vectors in a vector?

Tags: rust

Consider the following code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut rows: Vec<Vec<u32>> = Vec::from([
        Vec::from([1, 2, 3]),
        Vec::from([4, 5, 6]),
        Vec::from([7, 8, 9]),
    ]);

    let res: Vec<Vec<u32>> = rows.iter().map(|arr| arr.reverse()).collect();
}
```

I have an vector of vectors of integers, and I want to reverse each of the arrays present in `rows`.

Using this code gives a type annotation problem, where `map` function considers `arr` to be of the type `&Vec<u32>` while `.reverse()` expects it to be of the type `Vec<u32>`.

How can I overcome it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1. If you don't need the original `rows` anymore

You could use `into_iter`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let rows: Vec<Vec<u32>> = Vec::from([
        Vec::from([1, 2, 3]),
        Vec::from([4, 5, 6]),
        Vec::from([7, 8, 9]),
    ]);

    let res: Vec<Vec<u32>> = rows.into_iter().map(|mut arr| {arr.reverse(); arr}).collect();
}
```

or do it inplace using `iter_mut`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut rows: Vec<Vec<u32>> = Vec::from([
        Vec::from([1, 2, 3]),
        Vec::from([4, 5, 6]),
        Vec::from([7, 8, 9]),
    ]);
    rows.iter_mut().for_each(|mut arr| arr.reverse());
}
```

---

### 2. If you do need the `rows` afterwards:

```rust
fn main() {
    let rows: Vec<Vec<u32>> = Vec::from([
        Vec::from([1, 2, 3]),
        Vec::from([4, 5, 6]),
        Vec::from([7, 8, 9]),
    ]);

    let res: Vec<Vec<u32>> = rows.iter().map(|arr| {
        let mut arr = arr.clone();
        arr.reverse();
        arr
    }).collect();
}
```